# About Blender Hirise DTM Importer making Mars terrain

Tags: materials

I saw it on the github website, it can be used for Blender Hirise DTM Importer plugin of Blender 2.8+ version.

I followed the HiRISE DTM Importer for Blender tutorial and downloaded the .IMG file and .JP2 file from the HiRISE website and imported it into Blender 2.9. When I opened the EEVEE and Cycles renderers, the materials could not be displayed normally.

How do you make it? Can you share a tutorial on how to use Blender Hirise DTM Importer to create Mars terrain and add new materials in Blender 2.8 or Blender 2.9?

Download link of Blender Hirise DTM Importer plug-in that can be used in Blender 2.8+
https://github.com/phaseIV/Blender-Hirise-DTM-Importer

HiRISE DTM Importer for Blender
https://hemelmechanica.nl/hirise-docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

there is a new updated add on for this

see the post here
http://www.unmannedspaceflight.com/index.php?s=&showtopic=6878&view=findpost&p=248902

it is updated for the NEW api in blender 2.8+